# Stimulus nested (child) targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, stimulusjs

Is it possible (and is it appropriate) to use nested/child targets of parent target?

For example i have “N+“ menu items, each item (wrapper) contain link and list.
I could add `data-main-menu-target="menuItem"` to each of parent items and then iterate over them in controller loop using `this.menuItemTargets.forEach(...)`

But what's the best practice to find menu-item-link and menu-item-list for each menu-item target on each loop iteration?

In general i could add targets also for those elements, e.g. `menuItemLink` & `menuItemList`, but how then i could select them from parent `menuItem` target, Is it possible to do something like `menuItemTarget.find(this.this.menuListTarget)`?

To visualise the structure is the following:

```
data-controller="main-menu"
    data-main-menu-target="menuItem"
        data-main-menu-target="menuLink"
        data-main-menu-target="menuList"
....
    data-main-menu-target="menuItem"
        data-main-menu-target="menuLink"
        data-main-menu-target="menuList"
....
```

How then select "`menuLink`" for certain "`menuItem`" target on each loop?

Comment: ```menuItemTarget.find(this.this.menuListTarget)``` won't work, you can't chain this on this. If you want to select child in parent, you can use ```$('element', 'parent')...```. For example ```$('div[data-main-menu-target='menuLink']', 'div[data-main-menu-target='menuItem']')``` would return all items in all menuLink. Or use ```$('div[attr-item] > div[attr-list]').each(...)``` if you like it short, css operators work in jquery too

Comment: Hmm.. I've forgot that ``menuListTargets`` also will be a collection of created elements and it couldn't work this way as i thought. 
But maybe there's some "Stimulus" magic that allow to access child target from parent target based on initial data attributes in HTML

Answer (score 1):

You could structure your controller so that you have one `menu` controller that gets used on both the root menu and also the sub-menus within them. This could be recursively accessed from whatever is deemed to to be the root.

### Example Code

- In the HTML below we have a nav which contains `ul` for a menu, each child should be an `item` target.
- Within each `item` we may have a `link` target OR another sub-menu which itself is another `menu` controller and the pattern continues.

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu-list" data-controller="menu" data-menu-target="root">
    <li data-menu-target="item">
      <a data-menu-target="link">Team Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li data-menu-target="item">
      <ul data-controller="menu">
        <li data-menu-target="item">
          <a data-menu-target="link">Members</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menu-target="item">
          <a data-menu-target="link">Plugins</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menu-target="item">
          <a data-menu-target="link">Add a member</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-menu-target="item">
      <a data-menu-target="link">Invitations</a>
    </li>
    <li data-menu-target="item">
      <a data-menu-target="link">Cloud Storage Environment Settings</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

- In our controller we first determine if this controller's instance is the root, simply by checking `this.hasRootTarget`.
- Controllers only get access to their ['scoped' elements](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#scopes) so the root can only 'see' the children outside of the nested `data-controller='menu'`.
- We need to use `setTimeout` to wait for any sub-controllers to connect, there may be a nicer event propagation way to do this.
- You can access a controller on an element via the [`getControllerForElementAndIdentifier`](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#directly-invoking-other-controllers) method.
- From here we can determine the menu structure as an array of either a `link` target OR a nested array which itself will contain the sub `link` targets.
- We can use the [Node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method to map through each `item` and see what links are 'contained' within it.
- This approach could be refined to get you the structure you need to work with.

```js
class MenuController extends Controller {
  static targets = ['item', 'link', 'root'];

  connect() {
    if (this.hasRootTarget) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // must use setTimeout to ensure any sub-menus are connected
        // alternative approach would be to fire a 'ready' like event on submenus
        console.log('main menu', this.getMenuStructure());
      });
    }
  }

  getMenuStructure() {
    const links = this.linkTargets;

    return this.itemTargets.map((item) => {
      const child = item.firstElementChild;
      const subMenu = this.application.getControllerForElementAndIdentifier(
        child,
        this.identifier
      );
      const menuLinks = links.filter((link) => item.contains(link));
      return subMenu ? subMenu.getMenuStructure() : menuLinks;
    });
  }
}
```

### Notes

- We are accessing the DOM via the `firstElementChild` and this may not be the way we want to do things in Stimulus, but you could simply add another target type of 'sub-menu' to be more explicit and follow the pattern of finding the 'link' within each item this way.
- A reminder that you cannot put the `data-controller="menu"` on a `data-menu-target="item"` as this will remove the `item` from the parent scope. As per the docs on [scopes](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#scopes).

> that element and all of its children make up the controller’s scope.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But the idea is still that we will use some kind of loop filter to fetch nested link target within each item target? 
Based on your example `const menuLinks = links.filter((link) => item.contains(link));` 
We have item target and then to fetch its link target we manually iterate over all linkTargets and return only that contains in item target

So there's no short way in Stimulus to get sub-target for parent target, something like ``itemTarget->fetchLinkTarget`` that will do this automatically

Comment: I see what you are trying to do but I do not think Stimulus provides those kinds of primitives to work with. I would recommend either writing an abstract mixin type thing that makes this easier to do OR rethink the solution in the way of more controllers and then use events to 'talk' back to the parent root menu as per the docs.

Comment: Looks that you're right, it's ok to use simple classes or redone to multiple controllers as you advised. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from another conversation,

> A) For menuLink and menuList, you handle it by yourself: use CSS
> classes, and then use normal selectors. So, once you've used the
> menuItem target to find the menuItem you want, you would then do
> menuItem.querySelector('.menu-link'). Not a Stimulus solution, but
> it's pretty simple and it's nice to be able to "back out" and do
> things manually if you need to.
>
> B) I'm not sure what your overall Stimulus controller is meant to do,
> but it's possible that there should be a menu-item controller that
> lives on the menuItem target. Depending on what you're trying to
> accomplish, that could replace the main-menu controller or, more
> likely (because I'm assuming you are doing some "work" on the top
> level main-menu where you want to be aware of all of the "items"), in
> addition to the main-menu controller. With this setup, your main-menu
> controller could loop over the menuItem targets and, in each one,
> directly use its underlying controller instance - even calling methods
> on it. This is not something I showed on the tutorial, but it's not an
> uncommon pattern: you would expose the "controller instance" of the
> "menu-item" controller on its element - e.g.
> https://www.betterstimulus.... (the big difference in that example is
> that both of the controllers are on the same element - so adjust
> accordingly).

(c) **weaverryan**